# New Entry Button VBA Predicament

Tags: vba, excel

I am recently new to VBA and admit I am a novice. 
The procedure that I require is that a 'Button' is selected. The code is ran and the result is that a new row (which is a copy of the row above and contains several variables and data validations) is input below the last row. For a little context, "NEW" is selected, for every time the user has to fill in a new "Situation" BUT the new row must ALWAYS appear below the last entry; if that makes sense

Here is the macro code thus far:

```
Sub Macro6()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("A2:F2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Sorry for any novel mistakes, I only started VBA around 20 mins ago. I did ask a fellow colleague for help, however, we could not crack it

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is something, that will make your code workable the way you want it:

```
Sub Macro6()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = 1 + Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:F2").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("A" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As tips for next steps, once you have spent more than 20 minutes on VBA, try to avoid Select and Activesheet - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Furthermore, when you are working with the macro recorder, make sure to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to navigate around the Excel application. It will usually generate good results.

Comment: @MATTHEWHOLLIS - welcome. If it works for you, you may consider accepting the answer.